# Express 4 middleware when route is not found (finalhandler not called): how to check for it?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I set up the following Express 4 middleware stack:

```
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/test', testResponse);
app.use(checkAccessToken);
app.use(router);
app.use(sendResponse);
//Error Handling
app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
  // ... Do something here
});

function sendResponse(req, res) {
  res.json({
    data: res.locals.data,
    meta: res.locals.meta
  });
}
```

If I call the server with a route that doesn't exist (like GET /something) the function sendResponse just after the router handler is called and the caller gets a standard response instead of the usual message "Cannot GET /something", coming from the finalhandler module.
I thought instead that the error handler should have been called, but this is not the case.
Is there a way to force the router to emit an error if a route is not found or to check in the standard response handler if a route has not been matched?
I know that I can add a value in res.locals for any route that has a match and check for it in the standard response handler, but I'd like to use the "right" way to do it, rather than using a workaround.

Comment: Is change `app.use(sendResponse);` to `app.use(function(req, res, next) { next(new Error(404)); });` solve your problem? .

Comment: Not at all, because in this case the error 404 is raised even when the route is found

Comment: Do you call `next()` in router function to call `sendResponse`, right?

Comment: router function is the standard express router, so yes obviously there's a next() call, that in fact always calls my sendResponse (code added now above)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check `req.route`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: false}));

const router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    app.locals.test = 0;  
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    app.locals.test = 10;  
    next();
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    app.locals.test = 20;  
    next();
});

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.route)
        return next (new Error('404'));  
    next();
});

router.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.send(err.message);
})

router.use(function(req, res){
    res.send(app.locals.test + '');
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Yes! Checking req.route is what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use the following logic:

```
...

app.use(require('./routes/eInvoice'))
app.use(require('./routes/oauth2/client'))

// Status 404 (Error) middleware
app.use('*', function(req,res){
    res.status(404)
    if(req.headers.accept.indexOf('html'))
        res.render('404', { url: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl })
    else
        res.send("URL cannot found")
})

// Error handling
app.use(require("./middlewares/errorHandler"))

app.listen(config.operating.port, function() {
    console.log('Operating Server is listening HTTP port ' + config.operating.port)
})
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: You are sending the response in the routes files, I think, while I'm sending the response with the last middleware function. In your case you don't even need to add a '*' route, because express already handle this case nicely through the finalhandler module.

Comment: Yes you're right. I can remove '*' part. I'd writtent this code about two years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

The error handler is in case there was an uncaught error. No matching route is not an error.
I assume the middlewares called by your router don't return the response to the client and therefore you need the sendResponse middleware.
You can change that and return the response to the client in the router middlewares and after the router use a middleware that return the route not found error. If you got to this middleware it means no route was matched.

Comment: True, but in reality I have more than one hundred routes and I don't want to put the same call to sendResponse in all of them. It seems so neat and clean to have just one sendResponse (taking data from res.locals.data) as a middleware